# How to send PHP Notice and Warning to error_log instead of on webpage?

Tags: php, apache, error-handling, lamp

I am not sure why I can't find information about this on the internet but php prints notices and warnings on the web page, which is unacceptable. I know that I can turn it off programmatically on each page, but how do I set a config to just send these errors to my error log? I've been googling like crazy and can't figure it out.

Stuff like this:

```
<b>Notice</b>: Use of undefined constant LOG_ERROR - assumed 'LOG_ERROR' in  on line <b>12</b><br /> <br /> <b>Warning</b>: syslog() expects parameter 1 to be long, string given in
```

Comment: Whats your error logging set to in your php.ini?

Comment: error_logging? I have this: error_log = /var/log/syslog.log

Comment: The answer below is what I meant. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ini_set('display_errors', '0');
```

You can include that line at the top of any page, but it's preferred to set it in the php.ini file

```
display_errors = Off
```

Find 'display_errors' in the ini file and set it to off. Then whenever you need a page to display errors for debugging, you can just set:

```
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

At the top of the page.

Comment: I set display_errors = Off in both cli/php.ini and apache2/php.ini and it is still displaying. Also the warnings/notices aren't going to the syslog.

Edit: Had to restart apache2 to get the errors to not show, but they still do not show up in the syslog.

Comment: Make sure you've found the right one. There is sometimes two files you have to set them in which I can't quite remember for sure on that, but I'll check and get back with you.
ALSO, it's easy to accidentally set those values to the notes in the ini file rather than the actual assignments. So make sure when you do it, look through it carefully.  Also, could you give me the entire path to the files you set them in. Was it /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini ?

Comment: Yeah it was /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini and /etc/php5/cli/php.ini as i said i needed to restart apache so thanks for the answer! Now I just want to get the server to log the php warnings and notices to syslog and i'll be all set!

Comment: OH Also, first actually, I forgot to mention, you have to restart apache after changing anything in the ini file.

Comment: You can also do that in the ini file. I log mine to my own location so I can display them in my webmaster page.
You set:
error_log = /path/to/log

Comment: I have it set to error_log = /var/log/syslog.log but the warnings and notices don't go there, only syslog errors. the same warnings and notices that i shut off with the  display_errors = Off are not in the log.

Comment: Glad I could help. Server stuff is a pain and takes a while to get the hang of. Good luck.